# List of Subfolder names and file links in google sheets - script

Tags: script, google-drive, links, google-spreadsheets, google-workspace

I'm trying to get a Google Sheet list of file links in folders and subfolders which I'm keeping in Google Drive. It should look something like this:

[image: one main folder with a couple of subfolders inside]

I was googling and reading forums for a quite a time now but I managed to find only a few script examples and not all of them are working. I found one script which is not too bad as it brings a list of files with links in one folder. but I would like to get a list of files with links in subfolders. Ideally all folder links and item names would be listed in one cell with a separator "|". one of the best script examples I found so far is:

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow(["Name", "File-Id"]);


//change the folder ID below to reflect your folder's ID (look in the            URL when you're in your folder)
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0ByQ9Zp2ge-pzSjhKdHVWWk0wNnc");
var contents = folder.getFiles();

var cnt = 0;
var file;

while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    cnt++;

       data = [
            file.getName(),
            file.getId(),
        ];

        sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
};
```

and it brings results in a sheet

[image]

It would be much appreciated if anyone could help to get a better version of this code.

p.s.There's also a few bigger scripts I will need in a future which I'm willing to pay for. please message me if you're interested.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful: https://alicekeeler.com/2020/05/05/google-drive-list-the-files/

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace Guitar_Score below with the folder for which you want a listing with all subfolders
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'Guitar_Score';
  // file with this name will be saved in your goolge files
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();                  
  //listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet);
  traverseFolder(folder, sheet);
};

function traverseFolder(folder, sheet) { 
  listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet);  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    traverseFolder(subFolders.next(), sheet);
  }
}

function listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet) {
  var foldername = folder.getName();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();  
  sheet.appendRow( ['...', foldername] );    
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  } 
}
```